# Unexpected behaviour of RedirectToAction() (MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, redirecttoaction

I am having a problem when trying to use `RedirectToAction()`.

In my `RouteConfig.cs` I have something like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Custom",
            url: "myroot/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" }
        );
```

From my controller, if I try this:

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
    }
```

I get this URL:

```
http://localhost:51547/myroot/Home/About
```

Which is not what I expected. If I try this:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
```

I get this URL:

```
http://localhost:51547/Home/About
```

Which makes sense to me.

Can anybody explain why `RedirectToAction` is adding the `myroot/` prefix to the URL instead of matching the `Default` route?

Thank you!

Comment: Look like you are already in a method that has that prefix

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you for your response. Actually, I tested this within the default MVC applicaton. My method is this:

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }
And when I write this URL (http://localhost:12345/Home/Contact) it goes to the "About" view writting the myroot/ prefix to the url as I explained above.

Comment: You method is what? (you haven't shown any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your Route order as

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" }
    );routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Custom",
        url: "myroot/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work... not tested

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { area = "" });
```